# Error with ngrx on select

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm currently doing my first steps with Angular 2 and ngrx and I'm bit blocked... I want to manage the sate of opened attribute on sidenav element, particularly, mat-sidenav of Angular Material. For now, I want to observe (select) the state, I've initialised it with true but an error on mat-sidenav ngOnInit has occured. Maybe, someone see something that I miss...

> ERROR in src/app/docs/docs.component.ts(21,43): error TS2345: Argument
>   of type '"opened"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"sidenav"'.

TS Component Code

```
export class DocsComponent implements OnInit{
  sidenavState: Observable<{opened: boolean}>;
  @ViewChild('snav') public myNav: MatSidenav;


  constructor(private store: Store<{sidenav: {opened: boolean}}>){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.sidenavState = this.store.select('opened'); // <--- Error Line
  }



  fillerNav = Array(50).fill(0).map((_, i) => `Nav Item ${i + 1}`);

  fillerContent = Array(50).fill(0).map(() =>
    `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
       labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
       cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`);
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" style="min-width:250px;" [opened]="(sidenavState | async).opened" #snav fixedTopGap="56">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p *ngFor="let content of fillerContent">{{content}}</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

TS Reducer Code

```
import * as SidenavActions from './sidenav.actions';
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";

const initialState = {
    opened: true
};

export function sidenavReducer(state = initialState, action: SidenavActions.SidenavActions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SidenavActions.TOGGLE:
            return {
                ...state,
                opened: (state.opened ? false : true)
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

TS Action Code

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE';

export class Toggle implements Action {
    readonly type = TOGGLE;
}

export type SidenavActions = Toggle;
```

TS Main Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,

    CoreModule,
    DocsModule,
    MyMaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    StoreModule.forRoot({sidenav: sidenavReducer})
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

package.json Dependencies

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^5.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
```

Comment: What is the store.select is doing?

Comment: shouldnt that be this.store.select('sidenav.opened'); ?

Comment: Select is the same that fetch the state.  And sidenav.openede didn't work either.  ERROR in src/app/docs/docs.component.ts(21,43): error TS2345: Argument of type '"sidenav.opened"' is n│chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 530 kB [initial] [rendered]
ot assignable to parameter of type '"sidenav"'.

Comment: Solved. The error was on the name of construct and ngOnInit, element has to set the same value than forRoot variable

Answer (score 0):

this.sidenavState = this.store.select('sidenav','opened'); // this will work